# Cannot receive to get clicked button value in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I tried to get the button value when I click the button (onClick method).

I tried to do generally the way that is e.target.value but sometimes it returns an undefined or empty string. Even I tried to arrow function way that I find in here but still doesn't work. Could you help me with this problem? Which part is wrong or do I miss something?

This is the main part of my code:

```
updateProducts = e => {
    // e.preventDefault();
    let buttonValue = e.target.value;
    console.log(buttonValue);
    fetch('/data/MainProductsShoes.json', {})
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          productsInfo: data,
          // category_id: '',
        });
      });
};
```

and

```
<main className="contentsBody">
            <div className="contentsLink">
              <div className="viewAll">
                <button onClick={this.updateProducts} value="viewAll">
                  <span>전체보기</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div className="Shoes">
                <button onClick={this.updateProducts} value="shoes">
                  <span>신발</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div className="Clothes">
                <button onClick={this.updateProducts} title="clothing">
                  <span>의류</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div className="Supplies">
                <button onClick={this.updateProducts} title="acc">
                  <span>용품</span>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Here's the complete code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Main.scss';
import COLOR_LISTS from './colorList';
import Products from './ProductsInfo/Products';

export class Main extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      productsInfo: [],
    };
  }
  // const API = "DASDDADDAD" => 컴포넌트 마다 다 적용할수x
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/data/MainProducts.json', {})
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          productsInfo: data,
        });
      });
  }

  updateProducts = e => {
    // e.preventDefault();
    let buttonValue = e.target.value;
    console.log(buttonValue);
    fetch('/data/MainProductsShoes.json', {})
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          productsInfo: data,
          // category_id: '',
        });
      });
  };

  // updateProducts = () => {
  //   console.log('clicked');
  //   fetch('/data/MainProducts.json', {
  //     method: 'GET',
  //   })
  //     .then(res => res.json())
  //     .then(data => {
  //       this.setState({
  //         productsInfo: data,
  //         category_id: this.state.category_id,
  //       });
  //     });
  // };

  // showToProductDetailPage = () => {
  //   const { productsInfo } = this.state;
  //   productsInfo &&
  //     productsInfo.map((product, idx) => (
  //       <Products key={idx} productInfo={product} />
  //     ));
  // };

  render() {
    const { productsInfo } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="MainWrapper">
        <div className="sectionHeader">
          <div className="sectionTitle">
            <div className="sectionTitleCategory">
              <span className="categoryName">Men</span>
              <br />
              <br />
              <span>Men's 의류(12)</span>
            </div>

            <div className="sectionControl">
              <button>필터</button>
              <select name="list" className="productsFilter">
                <option value="newestOrdeer">신상품순</option>
                <option value="hightCostoOder">높은가격순</option>
                <option value="lowCostOrder">낮은가격순</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="contentsWrapper">
          <aside className="contentsSide">
            <div className="HorizontalLine" />
            <div className="colors">
              <span>색상</span>
              <ul className="colorLists">
                {COLOR_LISTS.map((color, idx) => {
                  return (
                    <li className="colorLayout" title="베이지" key={idx}>
                      <input type="checkbox" />
                      <label
                        className="checkboxLabel"
                        for="checkbox"
                        style={{ backgroundColor: color.colorProps }}
                      />
                      <span className="productColor">{color.color_name}</span>
                    </li>
                  );
                })}
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div className="sizes">
              <div className="HorizontalLine" />
              <span>사이즈</span>
              <div className="sizeLists">
                <button title="230">230</button>
                <button title="230">235</button>
                <button title="230">240</button>
                <button title="230">245</button>
                <button title="230">250</button>
                <button title="230">255</button>
                <button title="230">260</button>
                <button title="230">265</button>
                <button title="230">270</button>
                <button title="230">275</button>
                <button title="230">280</button>
              </div>
              <div className="HorizontalLine" />
            </div>
          </aside>

          <main className="contentsBody">
            <div className="contentsLink">
              <div className="viewAll">
                <button onClick={this.updateProducts} value="viewAll">
                  <span>전체보기</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div className="Shoes">
                <button onClick={this.updateProducts} value="shoes">
                  <span>신발</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div className="Clothes">
                <button onClick={this.updateProducts} title="clothing">
                  <span>의류</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div className="Supplies">
                <button onClick={this.updateProducts} title="acc">
                  <span>용품</span>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <article className="productsMapping">
              {productsInfo &&
                productsInfo.map((product, idx) => (
                  <Products key={idx} productInfo={product} />
                ))}
            </article>
          </main>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change you `updateProducts` function to receive a string value representing the product name:

```
updateProducts = (name) => {
    console.log(name);
    fetch('/data/MainProductsShoes.json', {})
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          productsInfo: data,
          // category_id: '',
        });
      });
  };
```

Then on each button pass the product name as an argument:

```
<button onClick={() => this.updateProducts('shoes')}>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Finally, I successfully receive the name well. If you don't mind, can I ask why my code doesn't work??

Comment: react uses syntactic events which are a bit different from the dom events. (https://en.reactjs.org/docs/events.html). You were also using `title` on a couple of buttons  and `value` on a couple of others, so maybe you were getting something unexpected.

Comment: oh, I see. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use `event.currentTarget.value` instead of `event.target.value`.

```
let buttonValue = e.currentTarget.value;
console.log(buttonValue);
```

- `event.target` points to the element where the click event triggered. In your case that can be either `span` inside the `button` sometimes and that is when you get `undefined` value.
- `event.currentTarget` points to the element where the event handler is attached which is the `button`.

I also notice some of the buttons have `title` property instead of `value` property.

```
             <div className="viewAll">
                <button onClick={this.updateProducts} value="viewAll">
                  <span>전체보기</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div className="Shoes">
                <button onClick={this.updateProducts} value="shoes">
                  <span>신발</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div className="Clothes">
                <button onClick={this.updateProducts} title="clothing">
                  <span>의류</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div className="Supplies">
                <button onClick={this.updateProducts} title="acc">
                  <span>용품</span>
                </button>
              </div>
```

Comment: @DOeat, check this out!!

Comment: oh got it! I will check it when I get back home! thank you so much!